# Ionic 3 Popover Click Outside Behavior

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

To close a popover , we usually click outside and it will close automatically. Let's say I clicked on a button outside, it will first close the popover and then you have to click again on the button to take action. Is there a way to override this behavior and once we click on an element outisde the popover,

1. Close the popover
2. Get action of the clicked element

Comment: Checkout **IonicBurger's** answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371040/how-do-i-interact-with-items-in-the-background-in-ionic-while-a-popover-is-activ/38372421#38372421

Comment: I think those are ionic 1.

Comment: Sorry about that, will retract my vote!